# How to CREATE TABLE copying "Default" and "Constraints" of the previous table in PostgreSql using PHP?

Tags: php, postgresql

I am not able to create table like/as with constraints and default values from another table that already exists.

I have tried following

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE schemas.a AS TABLE schemas.b";
```

This creates the table but no constraint or default value is copied.

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE schemas.a (LIKE schemas.b INCLUDING CONSTRAINTS)";
```

This creates the table with not null constraint only.
Still the primary key constraint and the default value is not being transferred.

Coding used in php

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE schemas.a (LIKE schemas.b INCLUDING CONSTRAINTS)";
pg_query($con, $sql);  //This is in the PHP
```

I want to create the table with all the constraints (primary, unique, not null) and default value that are set.

Comment: The code works outside of PHP? Not a `postgresql` user but seems strange that the behavior is related to PHP.

Comment: This has nothing to do with php, it is just about the PostgreSQL ```CREATE TABLE``` command.

Comment: CREATE TABLE Database.NewTableName
SELECT * FROM Database.ExistingTable

This will create a copy of your table including structure (minus the Primary Key link which you will want to set yourself after you copy it.  But this is a FAST way to duplicate a table that is similar to the new one you want to make, and then you can just make the edits to that table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following sql:

```sql
CREATE TABLE schemas.a (
    LIKE schemas.b
        INCLUDING ALL
);
```

For further information about the `CREATE TABLE` command have a look into the documentation: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html (Perhaps you need to switch to your version. Search for `like_option` to find the relevant information on the page.)

Comment: Don't know the problem but this work. Earlier i tried something like this but hit with an error. INCLUDING ALL works perfectly.